# Why is win32com in python not finding Excel.Application?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, win32com

I have code that uses win32com to open Excel in python and writes a pivot table. The code works perfectly on my desktop computer, but fails on my laptop. Both computers are running Python 3.7 in an Anaconda environment on Windows 10. I get the following error at this line of code:

```
Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\narob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Microtech\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_excel_pivot_tables.py", line 6, in <module>
    Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
  File "C:\Users\narob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Microtech\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\narob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Microtech\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\narob\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Microtech\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

I understand this to mean that win32com could not properly find "Excel.Application".

I have tried the following on the computer that shows the error:

- Reinstalling pywin32 (and running the post-install script)
- Reinstalling Excel
- Checking the registry - Excel.Application shows up
- Trying Excel.Application.16
- Trying other methods of dispatch in win32com
- Using the raw CLSID value

No luck with any of the above. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.